# Как правильно в Docker запустить контейнер с Apache?

Tags: apache, docker

Доброго дня!

Начал изучать Docker, запилил его на Ubuntu Server 14.02. Создал несколько контейнеров. Возник вопрос. Создаю контейнер 
docker run -i -t -name test -d -p 8888:80 ubuntu /bin/bash

Внутри контейнера ставлю apache2 через apt-get. Apache стартует и все работает. Выхожу из контейнера, соответственно он останавливается. Стартую контейнер снова и apache не работает, так как init скрипт не срабатывает. 
Погуглил, пробую собрать свой образ с Dockerfile.

```
FROM ubuntu
MAINTAINER Test 
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y
RUN apt-get install php5 libapache2-mod-php5 -y
RUN service apache2 start
CMD /bin/bash
```

Собираю контейнер с этим образом. Запускаю, захожу внутрь и apache не стартанул, если стартую вручную service apache2 start , то все окей. 
Пытаюсь сделать по другому. Добавляю в Dockerfile еще supervisor.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Test
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install apache2 supervisor php5 -y

ADD ./conf/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf.

ENTRYPOINT  ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
CMD ["-n", "-l -"]
```

Конфиг supervisor

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon         = true


[program:httpd]
command=/usr/sbin/apache2 -D FOREGROUND
redirect_stderr=true
```

Apache все равно не стартует. Как правильно развернуть его в контейнере, чтобы он был в автозапуске. И реально ли при этом подключится к контейнеру и получить bash?

Comment: ответ есть тут (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I18TNwZ2Nqg&t=1470s) на 33:04. Парень очень просто объясняет.

Answer (score 3):

Боюсь, я не могу помочь вам непосредственно с supervisord, пока нет времени с ним поиграться, но некоторое количество теории должно помочь.

Во-первых, философия докера предполагает, что в одном рабочем контейнере запускается один (и ровно один) процесс. Контейнеры потребляют настолько мало ресурсов, что эта на первый взгляд абсолютно непонятная затея оказывается абсолютно реализуема, и, в конечном счете, выигрышна: это равносильно простому программированию монолитной и компонентной архитектуры, и такой подход позволяет как раз-таки разбить приложение на переиспользуемые компоненты - например, не нужно засовывать redis во все контейнеры, потому что он и так идет отдельным контейнером. Это позволяет экономить место (вместо того, чтобы вложить редис в десяток образов достаточно иметь под рукой всего один образ с самим редисом) и обновлять приложение покомпонентно (достаточно пересобрать контейнер со своим приложением, чтобы обновить всю систему). В вашем случае supervisord не нужен просто потому, что у вас ровно один необходимый процесс - apache. Насколько понимаю, вашим `ENTRYPOINT` должен стать `["/usr/sbin/apache2"]`, а `CMD` - `["-D", "FOREGROUND"]`. После этого apache станет тем самым запрятанным в контейнер процессом и станет по факту его синонимом. В контейнере, де-факто, нет автозапуска: с точки зрения *захваченной* контейнером операционной системы она никогда не выключается, при каждом запуске контейнера она создается с нуля, и за запуск чего-либо отвечает тот самый корневой процесс (в обычном линуксе это init, в контейнере - все, что душа пожелает).

По поводу

> И реально ли при этом подключится к контейнеру и получить bash?

Да, эта возможность появилась в 1.какой-то версии и спасает ежедневно. Если предположить, что у вас запущен контейнер с именем `my-kool-apache`, то следующей командой вы можете *запустить еще один процесс* внутри контейнера и получить к нему доступ из хост-ос:

```
docker exec -ti my-kool-apache bash
```

флаги -ti обязательны и отвечают за прицепление текущего tty к этому контейнеру (я сам довольно кисло понимаю, что все эти слова значат).

В случае, если у вас сломался билд, то вы можете запустить последний собранный образ, просто найдя его в выводе консоли:

```
Step 1 : RUN apt-get update
 ---> Using cache
 ---> bbb8d81adb23 # <--- это то, что нам нужно - ID полученного образа

docker run --rm -ti bbb8 bash # флаг --rm нужен, чтобы контейнер самоудалился после выхода.
```

Это не всегда может сработать без переопределения ENTRYPOINT (по умолчанию это безобидный `/bin/sh -c`), см. следующую секцию.

Не могу не сказать по поводу ENTRYPOINT и CMD - первое является неизменяемой частью команды, в то время как второе - продолжение команды по умолчанию. Представьте, что у меня есть некоторый php-скрипт консольного приложения (пускай у него есть команды `serve` и `help`, вызов выглядит как `php script.php serve --port 8080`), для которого я хочу навсегда забить некоторые опции php.ini. Тогда мой dockerfile может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["php", "-d", "display_errors=on", "script.php"] # это "неизменяемая" часть команды, точка входа в приложение, грубо говоря - исполняемый файл
CMD ["serve", "--port", "8080"] # это команда по умолчанию
```

После этого простой старт контейнера вызовет мне следующую команду:

```
docker run php-script
=
php -d display_errors=on script.php serve --port 8080
```

Я могу с тем же успехом написать эту команду явно или подредактировать ее

```
docker run php-script serve --port 8080
docker run php-script serve --port 6556 --disable-cache
```

А вот такой позволит мне увидеть справку, используя все тот же контейнер

```
docker run php-script help
=
php -d display_errors=on script.php help
```

Другими словами, CMD формируется на лету (или берется CMD по умолчанию) и подставляется к ENTRYPOINT.

Последнее, о чем стоит сказать: контейнеризация не очень любит практику установки пакетов с помощью менеджера. В идеале один и тот же контейнер должен иметь идентичное содержимое, будь он собран хоть сегодня, хоть через два года, и, в идеале, контейнеры, представляющие приложение, должны собирать / комплировать его в процессе билда из предоставленных исходников.

Подводя итог: запускайте апач напрямую, пока у вас нет серьезной необходимости запускать кучу процессов внутри контейнера в автоматическом режиме (скорее всего, ее не будет никогда). Ставьте основным процессом то, для чего и создается контейнер; термин автозагрузки не очень применим к контейнерному workflow.

Comment: *контейнеризация не очень любит практику установки пакетов с помощью менеджера* — не слыхал о таком (и последующем в этом абзаце) до сих пор (хотя lxc вообще и docker-ом в частности инересуюсь уже давно). есть ли по этому поводу какое-нибудь развёрнутое обсуждение/изложение на каком-нибудь языке?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну на самом деле это я загнул немного. От контейнера требуется, чтобы MAJ.MIN предоставляемого пакета не зависели от времени сборки, и какой-нибудь PHP 5.3 не заменился незаметно для всех на 5.4 (это автоматически сделает бессмысленными прогоны CI на совместимость с 5.3). Если есть возможность выкачать конкретную версию из репы (со стандартными репозиториями такое не пройдет), то можно, конечно, выкачивать: цель не скомпилировать, а предоставить фиксированную версию. Официальные образы mysql и postgres качают бинарники, а PHP - компилируется.

Comment: понял. но это, скорее, уже требование, вытекающее из целей использования контейнеров. и, кстати, если это «серьёзный», не *rolling*-дистрибутив, то в рамках **одного релиза** в официальном репозитории, к примеру, *php-5.3* не «заменится» на *php-5.4*. ни «вдруг», ни специально. / номер сборки — да, конечно, может поменяться.

Comment: 12.10 вроде апгрейдил пхп

Comment: возможно, но под другим именем (не *php*, а что-нибудь вроде *phpNN*). и, естественно, пакет *php* никуда из репозитория **данного релиза** не «делся». хотя, теоретически, «убунтовцы» могли и такое «отмочить». за что «отмочившего» такое, наверняка, позже распяли «лучами ненависти».

Comment: продолжение: да и не только «лучами» — ведь это явное и грубейшее нарушение дистрибутивного *policy*.

Comment: Спасибо! Получилось запустить контейнер с Apache. Но вот интересно, что docker exec не выполняется, типа нет такой опции...

Comment: @mikonoid какая версия докера?

Comment: @Etki намек понял) Ставил из стандартного репо в Убунте и версия была 1.0.1, после этого поставил через 
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ | sudo sh
Версия стала 1.7 и появилась команда exec. Большое спасибо.